# Error encountered when trying to login on remote system

Tags: linux, ssh, users, openssh, metasploit

When trying to log on remote system using ssh, I encounter the following error :

`Unable to negotiate with 172.15.239.54 port 22: no matching host key type found.`

Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

How do I fix this?

Comment: probably your remote host doesn't support the cypher you are using, you can check with this option `ssh user@172.15.239.54 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa`

Comment: Hi, I suspect the metasploit tag has something to do with this. Are you maybe trying to downgrade the cypher of your ssh connection, but the server won't have that?

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I was trying to login to a remote system using the ssh

Comment: @admstg Yes this option works, I'm able to log in thanks very much. can I add that to my sshd_config file?

Comment: It will be in ssh_config on the client, not the sshd_config on Server side. man ssh_config can provide you the option of `HostKeyAlgorithms` to add ssh-rsa cypher.